# WPF bind data to TabControl of DataGrids

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to create a UI where I have a TabControl and in each tab there's a DataGrid. I'd like to dynamically add/remove tabs and also rows/columns to the DataGrid. Here's an example of code:

`Test.xaml`

```
<StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Add tab" Click="Button_Click"/>

        <Controls:MetroAnimatedTabControl x:Name="TabControl"
                                          TabStripPlacement="Left" 
                                          DisplayMemberPath="TabName">
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataContext="{Binding Context}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </Controls:MetroAnimatedTabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

And the codebehind

`Test.xaml.cs`

```
public class Tab
{
    public string TabName { get; set; }
    public DataTable Content { get; set; }

    public Tab(string name, DataTable content)
    {
        TabName = name;
        Content = content;
    }

    public Tab(string name, List<string[]> content)
    {

        Content = new DataTable();
        foreach (var item in content){
            Content.Columns.Add(item[0], typeof(string));
        }
        DataRow row = Content.NewRow();
        foreach (var item in content)
        {
            row[item[0]] = item[1];
        }
        Content.Rows.Add(row);
        TabName = name;
    }
}
public partial class Test: UserControl
{
    ObservableCollection<Tab> clsTabs = new ObservableCollection<Tab>();
    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        clsTabs.Add(new Tab("Animals", new List<string[]>() { new string[] { "Name", "Tiger" }, new string[] { "Tail", "Yes" } }));
        clsTabs.Add(new Tab("Vegetables", new List<string[]>() { new string[] { "Name", "Tomato" }, new string[] { "Color", "Red" }, new string[] { "Taste", "Good" } }));
        clsTabs.Add(new Tab("Cars", new List<string[]>() { new string[] { "Name", "Tesla" } }));

        TabControl.DataContext = clsTabs;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        clsTabs.Add(new Tab("New", new List<string[]>() { new string[] { "Name", "Something" }, new string[] { "Detail", "No" } }));
    }
}
```

It compiles, but there's nothing displayed in the window when you run the application. Most likely the data binding is wrong (especially to the DataGrid, because I have no idea how to do that with a class like mine).

In case it's not clear from the code, in my `Tab` class I have the `TabName` property for the tab name, and the `Content` DataTable should be the data source in the corresponding DataGrid. And I'd like to bind those to the xaml in a way, if the instances are modified, the UI also updates.

Is it possible to do this, or do I need to take a different approach?

Comment: Try updating data template definiton with <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Tab}"> and set ItemsSource property of DataGrid <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Content}" ...>

Comment: @NthDeveloper Tried it but no luck, still displays only an empty DataGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DataContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) is the context of the bindings in the current scope. The `TabControl` is a `ItemsControl` which has an `ItemsSource` that requires a `IEnumerable` (`IEnumerable<Tab>` in this case). You should introduce a view model which serves as the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` and in this case exposes the source collection `ObservableCollection<Tab>` which the `TabControl` is bound to. The view model generally will host all the data that the view can bind to. The view model usually implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) interface so that UI controls automatically update when the binding source changes.

Tab.cs (the data model that the tab controls will bind to):

```
public class Tab
{
    public string TabName { get; set; }
    public DataTable Content { get; set; }

    public Tab(string name, DataTable content)
    {
        TabName = name;
        Content = content;
    }

    public Tab(string name, List<string[]> content)
    {

        Content = new DataTable();
        foreach (var item in content){
            Content.Columns.Add(item[0], typeof(string));
        }
        DataRow row = Content.NewRow();
        foreach (var item in content)
        {
            row[item[0]] = item[1];
        }
        Content.Rows.Add(row);
        TabName = name;
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs (the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` that exposes the `Tab` collection as context of the bindings):

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.ClsTabs = new ObservableCollection<Tab>();

    ClsTabs.Add(new Tab("Animals", new List<string[]>() { new string[] { "Name", "Tiger" }, new string[] { "Tail", "Yes" } }));
    ClsTabs.Add(new Tab("Vegetables", new List<string[]>() { new string[] { "Name", "Tomato" }, new string[] { "Color", "Red" }, new string[] { "Taste", "Good" } }));
    ClsTabs.Add(new Tab("Cars", new List<string[]>() { new string[] { "Name", "Tesla" } }));
  }

  private ObservableCollection<Tab> clsTabs;

  public ObservableCollection<Tab> ClsTabs
  {
    get => this.clsTabs;
    set
    {
      if (Equals(value, this.clsTabs)) return;
      this.clsTabs = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Test.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Test: UserControl
{
    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (this.DataContext as ViewModel)?.ClsTabs.Add(new Tab("New", new List<string[]>() { new string[] { "Name", "Something" }, new string[] { "Detail", "No" } }));
    }
}
```

Test.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfTestRange.Main.Test">

  <!-- Set the DataContext of the Test control to an instance of ViewModel -->
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
  </UserControl.DataContext>

  <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
      <Button x:Name="Button"
              Content="Add tab"
              Click="Button_Click" />

      <MetroAnimatedTabControl x:Name="TabControl" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ClsTabs}"
                  TabStripPlacement="Left"
                  DisplayMemberPath="TabName">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="local:Tab">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Content}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>

  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I recommend that you have a look at [Microsoft Docs: Basic Data Binding Concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview#basic-data-binding-concepts), and MVVM ([Microsoft Docs: The Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) (mentions Xamarin.Forms but everything applies to WPF as well), [MVVM Pattern Made Simple](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple))

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Can you explain what is the purpose of the `[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]` in the ViewModel? I commented it out and the code worked, so what is the advantage having it, and how can I reference it or how/where do I need to implement it?

Comment: I have a followup question, when I add a new row to the datagrid, it updates automatically, but if I add a new column it only updates the UI if I switch to another tab and then back. So I assume it it only updates the columns when it needs to load the whole table again. Is there a way to make this update instant? (Worst case to trigger the table to load again)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Let's say I have 2 columns and 1 row at start. I add a new column, and in order for the UI to update, I need to add a new row also (so now I have 2 rows), in which only column3 has data? Or do I need to add column3 data to the existing row?

Comment: Yes that's the case. Sure, an example would be great. So in the end I'd like to have something that manages house expenses, where each tab is one year, and in each year-tab there's a DataGrid where the headers are the different expenses and the rows are the months (I've just used random names in the example). And have buttons for adding a new row (month) and another for adding column (type of expense). I think your first solution would be best, but if you got some insight from my scenario any other advice is appriciated

Comment: Doesn't have to be a `DataTable`, what other structure would you use? OK, I'll try to give an example. Let's say I have expenses for my house like: Heating, Electricity, Rent. So the column headers in the `DataGrid` are "Month", "Heating", "Electricity", "Rent". Now I have 7 rows of data for each month in this year, for example: {"July", "3€", "4€", "5€"}. Let's say I install internet to the house, so from now on I need a new expense type(new column to the `DataGrid`). So that's what adding a column means

Comment: Yes, your suggestion works too (that was also my first thought also) but then I thought It'd be fancy if I could reorganize the expenses by drag and drop (which is possible for columns but not for rows, I believe). But it's not that important actually

Comment: [MainWindow.xaml](https://pastebin.com/ZV3am8Kk), [TableRowData](https://pastebin.com/8anB1DEW), [MainViewModel](https://pastebin.com/MrpX77nW). Quick&dirty.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that these kinds of controls that generate content for multiple items should be populated using the `ItemsSource` property, not `DataContext`.

The line
`TabControl.DataContext = clsTabs;`
should assign to `TabControl.ItemsSource`

At that point you'll see in the Output pane

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Context' property not found on 'object' ''Tab' (HashCode=55467050)'. BindingExpression:Path=Context; DataItem='Tab' (HashCode=55467050); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')

The line
`<DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataContext="{Binding Context}" />`
has the previous problem *and* the wrong property name.  It should be
`<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Content}" />`
and then you should be good.